# keep current page in vuetify when items change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How to keep the current page in data tables in `vuetify` when the items is changed.

the current page is 2, add new item to items how to keep the current page 2

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/thanhtungvo/pen/PeVErM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding items to the data table, you can save the current page number and re-use it after successfully adding items.

Demo: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/odmEER?editors=0011

```js
showFullMats (item) {
  // store current page number first
  this.prevPage = this.pagination.page;

  // codes for adding items...

  // reset to page number before adding item
  this.$nextTick().then(()=>{
    this.$set(this.pagination, 'page', this.prevPage);
  });
}
```