# Vuetify v-data-table pagination: options.page value changes in mounted()

Tags: pagination, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm using Nuxt 2.15.8 and @nuxtjs/vuetify 1.12.1 (Vuetify 2).

I have a v-data-table with server-side pagination, each row/item has a link to a detail page. Everything works fine.

When user navigate in the v-data-table, I add the page number in the URL `?page=2` so when user click the browser back button from the detail page I can reset the v-data-table where they were. (I'm doing the same with the search criteria and it's working perfectly).

If I log this.options.page in created(), I have the correct number, but **in mounted() it's reset to 1 and I can't understand why**.

Calls to API are fired from the watch on options.

The template

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :options.sync="options"
/>
```

The script (it's doing the same thing if I preset 1 or 0...)

```js
data() {
  return {
    options: {
      page:
        this.$route.query && this.$route.query.page
          ? Number(this.$route.query.page)
          : 0
    }
  }
}
```

I tried so many things to fix it (adding a flag to prevent multiple calls to API, resetting options.page after API call but ended up with two calls...) that I can't list all of them here.

I reckon I probably don't get a grasp of the lifecycle of Nuxt and the v-data-table so any light on this will really be appreciated! Best will be a working example :* Any information I can give you to help, please ask.

The only subject I found related to my problem is [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291778/when-retreiving-state-of-data-table-from-vuex-pagination-is-not-updated), but with no answer.

Thanks!

Comment: As for the lifecycle: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks @kissu, how do you do the color for the code? It's been twice you edited one of my post. ^^ I put four space before the line but it stays grey.
As for the lifecycle, I kind of understand it, the only thing I can make of it with the v-data-table it's probably the template updating the value of page but I don't understand why.

Comment: For the edit, you can click on `edit` and see the actual updated snippet. Prefixing it with 3 backticks and putting either `html` or `js` is enough usually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the page is reset to 1 when the items change. You can solve it with the following:

```html
<v-data-table
  v-if="items.length"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :options.sync="options"
/>
```

Comment: Also see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442492/keep-current-page-in-vuetify-when-items-change